Is it possible to format strings in C++ like Python's f string?
For example in Python:
name = "John"
age = 30
print(f"My name is {name} and I am {age} years old.")

This would output: "My name is John and I am 30 years old."
Is there a similar way to format strings in C++?  I know about std::stringstream and std::printf, but they seem more verbose and error-prone compared to Python's f-strings.
Is there a way to achieve similar string formatting in C++ like in Python? If so, what are the best practices and libraries to use?

Just copy/pasting the title of the post on any good search engine, picks up the dupes. The downvote button  recommends making research effort.

C++20 <format>, C++23 <print>, otherwise open source 3rd party {fmt}.

You can't embed variable names in string literals to have them mapped to variables as you can in python. You need to supply the variables as arguments to the function you use separately.
The most similar way would be to use std::print which is available since C++23:
#include <print>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string name = "John";
    int age = 30;
    std::print("My name is {} and I am {} years old.\n", name, age);
}

In C++20, you could use std::format instead:
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string name = "John";
    int age = 30;
    std::cout << std::format("My name is {} and I am {} years old.\n", name, age);
}


It'd be nice with a comment about why it was downvoted so I have a chance to fix whatever it is that makes the answer not useful.

Probably they expect "Hello { foo + bar }" kind of syntax with embedded arguments

@AlexeyS.Larionov Okay... I don't see how that would be possible and I can't change the language. Jeez, more downvotes... What is it with this answer that triggers people to downvote? Please give me a hint.

Yes, I know, it's 2024 and most people should already be using C++20, but std::format and std::print are from https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt, AFAIK. If you can't use a modern compiler, you can use this library with C++11 or C++14.

@jabaa Yeah, and many libraries within "the standard library" comes from someone (or a bunch of people) putting a lot of effort into a useful library. Like std::chrono and std::filesystem etc.

Not really similar. OP wants interpolated strings which C++ sorely lacks.

@TedLyngmo Ah, okay. I didn't know this. fmtlib was the first library that I knew of that made it into the standard library.

@n.m.couldbeanAI The question is "Is it possible to format strings in C++ like Python's f string?" The answer is: "No, but you can do this". The implicit "No" is contained in "The most similar way would be to use ..."

@n.m.couldbeanAI True. What I put in the answer is the most similar I could think of in hope that it'd help somewhat at least.

@jabaa If anything, the iostreams way is more similar to Python f-strings than anything else (clunky and noisy but the same core idea).

@n.m.couldbeanAI I think the actual formatting similarities with {:-30} etc makes std::print/std::format more similar to pythons f-strings than using iostreams and iomanipulators.
